# Is there any way to write formulae using own properties we have sent while tracking in mixpanel?

Tags: events, statistics, analytics, mixpanel, event-tracking

I have a app where a hiring manager posts a job and hires job seekers.

I have placed two tracking events.

1. Job Hired (which will be tracked once the job seeker gets hired for a particular job)
2. Job Not Hired (which will be tracked if the job seeker is not hired for a particular job)

For both tracked events I have sent Job id as an Property.

Now I want to track the average candidate matches (i.e., from job post creation to hire) using mixpanel.

My query is can I write a formulae using my own property that  I have sent while tracking(i.e. Job id)

By placing both the events in the metrics of mixpanel and trying to write custom formulae as Sum of total events of unique Job ids divided by that particular Job id.
The issue I'm facing is that I'm not able to get that Job id in metrics which is tracked in events.

My expectation is to achieve the custom formulae as:

- Sum of total events of unique Job ids divided by that particular Job id.

Where Job id is provided in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVhE1.png)